# Return list element based on comparison of two other lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to return the element of a list based on a comparison between two other lists.

List 1 is a list of file names created from using `glob.glob(path)`.

List 2 is identical to the first, but has the filenames parsed into datetimes using `datetime.datetime.strptime`.  It is by definition the same length as the first list.

List 3 list is like the second, in that it is a list of datetimes parsed from a list of filenames.  The lists of filenames are related, but not necessarily the same length.

What I am trying to do is return the filename (List 1) that corresponds to the last datetime in List 2 prior to a specific element of List 3.  It's confusing, I know.  Sorry about that.

I know that using `next` is a quick way to return values from a list based on comparisons, but I haven't found a way to use it to return a value from a list outside the comparison.

Here's what I have:

```
# get list of mat files and extract corresponding times
matFiles = []
matFileTimes = []
matFilePattern = re.compile('\\.*(\w*\s*\w*\s*)(\d+.\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)(\s*\w*\s*\d*)?\.mat$')
for name in glob.glob(filePath[0] + '\*.mat'):
    event = re.search(matFilePattern, name)
    matFiles.append(event.group(0))
    matFileTimes.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(event.group(2),'%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S-%f'))

self.matFiles = sorted(matFiles)            
self.matFileTimes = sorted(matFileTimes)

if 'audio' in listdir(filePath[0]):
    audioFiles = []
    audioFileTimes = []
    audioFilePattern = re.compile('\\.*(\w*\s*\w*\s*)(\d+.\d+.\d+\s+\d+.\d+.\d+.\d+)?\.wav$')
    for name in glob.glob(path.join(filePath[0], 'audio') + '\*.wav'):
        audioEvent = re.search(audioFilePattern, name)
        audioFiles.append(audioEvent.group(0))
            audioFileTimes.append(datetime.datetime.strptime(audioEvent.group(2),'%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S-%f'))

    self.audioFiles = sorted(audioFiles)
    self.audioFileTimes = sorted(audioFileTimes)

    for each in audioFileTimes:
        self.eventMenu.addItem(datetime.datetime.strftime(each, '%b %d %Y, %I:%M:%S %p'))
else:
    for each in matFileTimes:
        self.eventMenu.addItem(datetime.datetime.strftime(each, '%b %d %Y, %I:%M:%S %p'))
```

Then later (in a different class function):

```
if 'audio' in listdir(self.filePath):
            fileToLoad = next(dt for dt in reversed(self.matFileTimes) if dt <= self.audioFileTimes[self.eventMenu.currentIndex()])
```

As it's implemented, `next` returns the datetime from "matFileTimes" that occurs immediately prior to the datetime indicated by the "eventMenu".  What's the quickest Pythonic way to return the element of "matFiles" that corresponds to the "matFileTime" datetime?

Suggestions on better ways to do anything shown are also appreciated - I'm a bit new at this.

Comment: Not sure if I understood correctly. How about adding `fileToLoad = self.matFiles[self.matFileTimes.index(fileToLoad)]`. An idea for easier handling is maybe keeping things in a dict FileTimes->Files instead of separate lists.

Comment: That works, actually.  The dict idea would take some tweaking but it might be worth it in the long run.

Comment: So I turned it into an answer. Corrected the variable name on the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quickest way to get a result is using the index of the file time element and get the element with the same index of the file name list:

```
if 'audio' in listdir(self.filePath):
    timeToLoad = next(dt for dt in reversed(self.matFileTimes) if dt <= self.audioFileTimes[self.eventMenu.currentIndex()])
    fileToLoad = self.matFiles[self.matFileTimes.index(timeToLoad)]
```